Is it possible to have a variable name that changes?
I was thinking about some python code that I had recently written, and since I like to think of how the libraries code out their capabilities, I wanted to figure out a bit of code that takes a function and runs it.
That function probably was layed out like this:
def run_func(func):
    func()

but it also takes an input for the normal inputs that you would give it. So let's say you have this function, add(x, y) but as you can see, it takes two inputs. So the way you would run that function like this:
run_func(add, [3, 2])

meaning the definition of the function could be this:
def run_func(func, inputs = []):
    ...

I got to this trying to figure out the mystery:
def run_func(func, inputs = []):
    for x in range(len(inputs)):
        variable{{x}} = inputs[x] # means that the variable is variable followed with the value of x
    num_inputs = len(inputs)
    func(inputs[0], ..., inputs[num_inputs])

So my question is this: Can you have a variable name that changes depending on some expression?
EDIT: *args and **kwargs don't work because  they are a list and a dictionary respectively and that would only have two arguments sent into the function

run_func(func, inputs = []):: setting a default argument of [] is dangerous practice in Python; don't do that. Use None as default, and then an if None: inputs = [] in the function body.

maybe useful, singledispatch and probably have a look to custom decorator

don't use mutable objects as default value, you may have undesired side effects

Sorry, what's the problem exactly? Are you not aware of argument unpacking? i.e. func(*inputs). There are existing questions about that: Pass a list to a function to act as multiple arguments → Expanding tuples into arguments. Otherwise, maybe this is relevant? How do I create variable variables?

After some thought, this seems like an XY problem. Problem X is passing inputs to func, which you can solve with unpacking (func(*inputs)). Problem Y is "a variable name that changes", variable{{x}}, which is a dead end because even if you got that, you'd still need to name every new variable when passing them to func.

Use a (keyword) argument that takes a tuple of arguments to be passed on to the function. Then pass the args argument to the function as func(*args). The latter notation, *args, will expand the separate arguments automatically.
def run_func(func, args=()):
    return func(*args)

and you have
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

import math
def offroot(value):
    return math.sqrt(value**1.1)

Call as
>>> run_func(add, args=(2, 3))
5
>>> run_func(offroot, args=(10,))  # note: `(10,)` to make it a tuple
3.548133892335755

(This is something that, for example, SciPy does for various of its functions. See for example scipy.optimize.leastsq(), which takes a function, and an args argument that takes arguments to pass to that function.)
If you ever need keywords instead of plain argument, a similar thing exist with **kwargs instead, where kwargs is a dict instead of a tuple.

This all looks good, but why a keyword argument specifically? That's not required.

If you want a generic run_func that works on all possible functions, you'll have to use both *args and **kwargs simultaneously, like below:
def run_func(func, *args, **kwargs):
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

assert run_func(add, 2, 3) == 5
assert run_func(add, a=4,b=5) == 9


